# how to get the console output of docker-compose exec of a detached container

Tags: docker-compose

I've run in detached mode docker-compose up.

I have then run docker-compose exec container_name command
and i had nothing, so I have then run docker-compose exec -it container_name bash to get the shell and i got nothing either.

I have tried these command but I have no output from the first command and i dont have access to the shell with the second command. Do you know how i can have output or access the shell?

I am under macos x catalina 10.15.7. I have tried to reboot but it's the same.

docker-compose build and docker-compose up are running correctly

note docker ps -a gives me the same container id as docker-compose without the #1 at the end (react-wagtail-blog_web_cont with docker ps -a and react-wagtail-blog_web_cont_1 with docker-compose ps).

I can access my react-wagtail-blog_web_cont container with docker exec -it react-wagtail-blog_web_cont bash...

Thank you

Comment: did you try  `docker-compose exec container_name sh` ?

Comment: yes it s the same. i run the commands and i dont have anything, no error message, no output, nothing

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to see the normal log output you can use `docker logs <container>` where container is the container name or hash. To find that, just run `docker ps`

Also if you want to see the logs realtime as they come use `docker logs -f

See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)